# delegate xml file to detect the latest source from snapshot cm

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol, snapshot, snapshotcm

i am about to automate nightly build using Cruisecontrol. I just need a step in which writing an xml script to help find out the latest version of snapshot found in snapshotCM. Anybody has any idea how to go about writing such a script?

Comment: Can you specify what the "latest" version is? You can have multiple branches in a project, so you'd have various heads with latest snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the snapshot that was most recently created you could parse the output of

```
sslist -C -H -h server /path/to/project
```

and sort the "Create Dates:".